# How to get clicked image inside target div from source div which contain some images

Tags: javascript, html

Q: How to get clicked image inside target div(id="p1") from source div(id="p2") which contain some images.

current result: Only the last image is displayed.Please suggest other logic, if I am Wrong.
P.S only javascript is required.

Some logic is required before {document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="";}i.e the last line of the script code. So that exact clicked image is displayed rather than the last image,which is according to the current logic

### Below is the code snippet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
.main{
    height:400px;
    width:200px;
    margin:0px auto}
.p1{

        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        background-size: 100% auto;
        border-style:outset;
        border-radius:2px;
        }
.images{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border-radius:5px;
        }
</style>

<body >
<div class="main" >
<div id="p1" class="p1"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
<div id="p2">
 <input type="image" class="images"  id="obj0" name="obj" onclick="myFunction()" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-511058.jpg"/></br>
 <input type="image" class="images" id="obj1" name="obj" onclick="myFunction()" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-380016.jpg"/></br>
 <input type="image" class="images" id="obj2" name="obj" onclick="myFunction()" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-293063.jpg"/></br>
 <input type="image" class="images" id="obj3" name="obj" onclick="myFunction()" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-611834.jpg"/></br>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction(){
                    var x=document.getElementsByName("obj");
                    y=x.length;
                    for(var i=0;i<y;i++){
                     hi = document.getElementById('obj'+i).src;
                     //alert(hi);  uncommenting I can get url of each picture
                     document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="<img src='"+hi+"' height=100px ;width=100px centre />";
                    }

}
 </script> 
 </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why not pass in the unique id of the input image as a parameter to the myFunction()? e.g. myFunction("obj0"), myFunction("obj1"), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an argument that passes the ID of something that was just clicked. Then you need to get the attribute of that ID that has been passed.

Here you go:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .main {
        height: 400px;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    .p1 {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-size: 100% auto;
        border-style: outset;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .images {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="p1" class="p1"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="p2">
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj0" name="obj" onclick="myFunction(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-511058.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj1" name="obj" onclick="myFunction(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-380016.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj2" name="obj" onclick="myFunction(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-293063.jpg" /></br>
            <input type="image" class="images" id="obj3" name="obj" onclick="myFunction(this)" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/flowers-and-plants/flowers/clip-art-flowers-611834.jpg" /></br>
        </div>
        <script>

            function myFunction(id) {

                document.getElementById("p2").onclick = function () {
                document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "<img src='" + id.getAttribute("src") + "' height=100px ;width=100px centre />";

                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```